# React Native Infinite loop with Redux dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, infinite-loop

I have a simple program that retrieve some remote data and set to redux store and then display. Got an infinite loop at the end, using all kinds of methods described everywhere, just doesn't work. I believe it might be a small error, just cannot figure it out.

**Component**:

```
const OrdersScreen = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        props.getCurrentOrders();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
          ....
        </>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return state;
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        getCurrentOrders
    }, dispatch)
};
  
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OrdersScreen);
```

**Action:**:

```
export function getCurrentOrders() {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {

        var userID = getState().authReducer.user.local.email;

        fetchServer('mGetOrders', { userID: userID })
            .then((res) => {
                dispatch({ type: 'GET_ORDERS', orders: res });
            })
    }
};
```

**Reducer:**

```
export default function orderReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_ORDERS':
            return {
                ...state,
                orders: action.orders,
            }
        ...
```

**Store:**

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

I already tried everything I can find from the web, but none of them work. Really weird for me. A big thanks to anybody who can help me out of this.

Comment: Where is `OrdersScreen` being rendered? If it is being remounted by parent/ancestor then that seems like it could cause looping on `props.getCurrentOrders();`.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese. `OrdersScreen` is in a `StackNavigator` which is embedded into a `TabNavigator`, and `OrdersScreen` is being rendered by calling `props.navigation.navigate('OrdersScreen')` from some other page.

Comment: Shoot, I guess that's on me as I meant for you to provide the code where `OrderScreen` is being rendered so that we may see if anything is causing it to mount/unmount/mount.

Comment: @DrewReese , you are correct. I connect the store the RootNavigator for some reason, and it causes the infinite loop. Thanks so much for your help on that.